# How to express the volatility of two correlated Ito processes $Wt_1, Wt_2$ expressed in terms of $W_t$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, itos-lemma

Having two correlated Ito processes
($W_t^1$ and $W_t^2$ are correlated Brownian motions with correlation $\rho$)

$dX_{t} =\mu_{1} dt + \sigma_1  dWt_1 $

$dY_{t} = \mu_{2} dt + \sigma_2 dWt_2 $

How can the below be proven algebraically ?

$\sqrt{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 +2 \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \rho} \ \ dW_t = \sigma_1 dW_t^1 + \sigma_2 dW_t^2$

Comment: Are you trying to express it in terms of a third Brownian motion or in term of either one of $W^1$ or $W^2$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What can be shown is that the above expressions are equal in probability.
First check the distribution. As any linear combination of a Gaussian is Gaussian the right hand side is Gaussian - the left hand side too. Then we need the 2 moments:

The expected values - it is zero ... easy to see.

Next what you did not specify is that the correlation between $dW_t^1$ and $dW_t^2$ is $\rho$ then the variance can be calculated by
$$
VAR[\sigma_1dW_t^1+\sigma_2dW_t^2] = \sigma_1^2 VAR[dW_t^1] + 2 \sigma_1 \sigma_2 Covar[dW_t^1,dW_t^2] + \sigma_2^2 VAR[dW_t^2]
$$
which equals
$$
\sigma_1^2 dt + 2 \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \rho dt + \sigma_2^2 dt.
$$

On the other hand the variance of the lhs:
$$
VAR[\sqrt{\sigma_1^2 + 2 \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \rho+ \sigma_2^2} dW_t] = (\sigma_1^2 + 2 \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \rho+ \sigma_2^2) VAR[dW_t]
$$
and this is 
$$
(\sigma_1^2  + 2 \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \rho  + \sigma_2^2) dt,
$$
exactly what we needed.

Comment: Nice answer but just a pedantic remark: $\text{VAR}[dW_t^i] = dt$ not $t$, same point for covariance.

Comment: I have changed this just some seconds ago ;)

Comment: Wow that was fast ;)

Comment: @Quantuple Also, pedantically : $\textrm{VAR}[dW_t^i]$ has no mathematical meaning. ;-)

Comment: the dXYZ notion is not perfect but you get used to it, right? ;)